# Convergence of the series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a textbook in which authors wrote the following inequality
$$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{x+k}\right| \le \dfrac1{x+n+1}.$$
I could not explain why it's true. If it was wrong, how can we prove the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{x+n}, 0<x<+ \infty$ converges uniformly.

Comment: My first intuition is that you group your sum by pairs, to eliminate the odd  $(-1)^k$ . Have you tried that? What have you tried?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, so to make things easier assume $(-1)^{n+1}=1$.

Comment: @chubakueno follow your hint I just get an inequality like $|a-b| \le a, a,b>0$. This inequality is true iff $b \le 2a.$ It doesn't make the problem to be easier. I think.

Comment: The sum is alternating and the absolute value of the terms decrease to $0$. So, your inequality follows. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: Thank you @David Mitra. I got it. Your explanation is very nice.